# Ubuntu 11.10 Magic Mouse Speed Fix?

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, bluetooth

I connected my Magic Mouse to my computer. My problem is that the mouse is too fast, the lowest speed in `settings > mouse & touchpad` that is still really to fast. I searched in the Internet but everything I founded didn't work.

Somebody who knows what I have to do?

Thanks :)

Comment: This might be helpful (it's for a different type of mouse but the method should be the same) http://patrickmylund.com/blog/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Answer (score 0):

this script could help:

https://github.com/rubo77/mouse-speed

you only have to configure the identifier of your mouse in the head of the script